# Flutter: Is it possible to set vertical alignment in text lines at height> 1.0?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, material-design, figma

All texts in **Figma** have some height, for example **1.5**, but when I set that **height** to the **TextStyle**, all lines with the new height are aligned to the bottom.

[image: See picture]

If using **Center** or **Align** widgets - wrong result. Examples has bottom vertical alignment in their lines. Like on bottom screenshots.

[[image: Text screenshots2]

Is there a possibility to set vertical alignment in flutter **Text** wiget for every line? Or maybe someone has some helpful tips to solve the problem?

```dart
    Text(
      'Example\nExample',
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      style:TextStyle(
        height: 2.5,
        fontSize: 20,
      ),
    );
```

**Solution:**

As [user1032613](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1032613/user1032613) suggested, such a solution helped.

[image: Result text picture]

```dart
    final text = 'Example Example\nExample Example';
    const double height = 2.5;
    const double textSize = 16.0;
    const double bottomPadding = (height * textSize - textSize) / 2;
    const double baseline = height * textSize - height * textSize / 4;
    final Widget textWidget = Container(
      color: const Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: bottomPadding),
      child: Baseline(
        baselineType: TextBaseline.alphabetic,
        baseline: baseline,
        child: Text(
          text,
          style: const AppTextStyle(
            height: height,
            fontSize: textSize,
            color: const Color(0xFFaa3a3a),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is a property called `leadingDistribution` which can be used for that:

```
Text(
    'text',
    style: TextStyle(
        height: 2.0,
        leadingDistribution: TextLeadingDistribution.even,
        ),
)
```

From comments:

*After modifying this field, the hot reload will not take effect and will require a hot restart*

Comment: Note: After modifying this field, the hot reload will not take effect and will require a hot restart.

Comment: @ipcjs you saved me from banging my head in figuring out why this is was not working.

Comment: It worked after hot restart thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This is a quite common problem in Flutter when using custom fonts.

The solution our team currently uses is either use a `Padding` or a `Baseline` widget and manually tweak the text to make it appear vertically centered.

Comment: Thanks, I thought there was a way to get it right, instead of dancing with the paddings.

Comment: Adding manual tweaks is very difficult to maintain on larger projects. I ended up using the leadingDistribution property in textstyle. this solved it throughout my app.

Comment: @LeeHiggins We have tried `leadingDistribution` as well, but it did not solve the problem for us. In fact, it did not make any visible difference in our tests. I'm glad it worked for you, but it's probably a different issue or a different cause in your case.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by setting `textHeightBehavior` property of `Text`.

```
          Text(
            'text',
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black,
              height: 16 / 12,
            ),
            textHeightBehavior: const TextHeightBehavior(
              applyHeightToFirstAscent: true,
              applyHeightToLastDescent: true,
              leadingDistribution: TextLeadingDistribution.even,
            ),
          ),
```

Most important thing is to set `leadingDistribution` as `TextLeadingDistribution.even`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little bit late, but maybe my answer could be helpful for someone.
I had a Column with elements inside. Children elements contain `Text` and `Space` widgets:

```
     ...
     Text(
          _locale.nutritionEditDishTimeTitle.toUpperCase(),
          textAlign: TextAlign.end,
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Palette.codGray,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            fontSize: ScreenUtil().setSp(18),
            fontFamily: "Geometria",
          ),
        ),
      Spacer(flex: 15),
...
```

[image: On this image my text is not wrapped and has little bottom padding]

We have a little space under text and it's a problem cause it will be bad for pixel-perfect design implementation. After I made this change the problem was gone:

```
     ...
       SizedBox(
                height: ScreenUtil().setSp(20) * MediaQuery.textScaleFactorOf(context),
                 child: Align(
                 alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  child: Text(
                _locale.nutritionEditDishTimeTitle.toUpperCase(),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.end,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Palette.codGray,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: ScreenUtil().setSp(18),
                    fontFamily: "Geometria",
                  ),
                ),
              ),
),
              Spacer(flex: 15),
    ...
```

The text was wrapped and the size became normal:

[image: Image after change]

Comment: As I understand, that's because you set up the `height` parameter (And height 1.0 is enough to fix it in most popular cases). Thats can be ok for single line cases, but will not work for multi line text. And of course in this thread I found some general solution for this text issues. So If someone know it, or know some articles where it described. Still will be happy to see it. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

One way:

```
Align(
 alignment: Alignment.center, 
 child: Text("Text"),
),
```

Another way:

```
Center(
   child: Text("Hello World", textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
),
```

Comment: No, it's for Text widget alignment, but don't work for Text in every line.

Comment: This does not fix the issue, since the line height space is added in the text widget. So you are just centering a text widget, which then has some space at the top, and so the text is not vertically centred.